# A DataTable which having id from other datatables, Need to transform this datatable to replace ids with their datatable name column value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have N datatables, where N-1 datatables are representing some entities and 1 representing relationship between these entities.

like 
**Entity Country**

```
Country DATATABLE

ID    | Country Name | Country Code
------------------------------------
ID1   | USA          | USA
ID2   | INDIA        | IND
ID3   | CHINA        | CHI
```

**Entity Continent**

```
Continent DATATABLE

ID     | Continent Name | Continent Code
------------------------------------
IDC1   | NORTH AMERICA  | NA
IDC2   | SOUTH AMERICA  | SA
IDC3   | ASIA           | AS
```

**Entity Company**

```
Company DATATABLE

ID    | Company Name   | Company Code
------------------------------------
CM1   | XYZ Company    | XYZ
CM2   | Fun Company    | Fun
CM3   | ABC Company    | ABC
```

**Relationship among these.**

```
Company_Country_Continent_Relationship DataTable 

ID    | Company        | Country    |  Continent     | Some Value1     | Some Value 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
R1    | CM1            | ID1        |  IDC1          | 100             | 150
R2    | CM2            | ID2        |  IDC3          | 200             | 200
R3    | CM3            | ID1        |  IDC1          | 150             | 250
R4    | CM1            | ID3        |  IDC3          | 100             | 150
R5    | CM2            | ID1        |  IDC1          | 200             | 200
R6    | CM3            | ID2        |  IDC3          | 150             | 250
R7    | CM1            | ID2        |  IDC3          | 100             | 150
R8    | CM2            | ID3        |  IDC3          | 200             | 200
R9    | CM3            | ID3        |  IDC3          | 150             | 250
```

Now I need to generate another relationship table, which will hold Name instead of ID.
In this example relationship data is storing ID for company, country and continent, now I want to transform these id value to there name i.e . instead or CM1  - XYZ Company.

For this transformation, I am using a method `TramnsformRelationshipData`, and it is working correctly.

```
    public static DataTable TramnsformRelationshipData(DataTable relationshipData, Dictionary<string, DataTable> mapping)
    {
        DataTable transformedDataTable = null;
        if (relationshipData == null || mapping == null )
           return null;

        transformedDataTable = relationshipData.Copy();

        foreach (DataColumn item in relationshipData.Columns)
        {
            if (mapping.ContainsKey(item.ColumnName))
            {
                var instanceData = mapping[item.ColumnName];
                if (instanceData == null)
                    return null;

                foreach (DataRow row in transformedDataTable.Rows)
                {
                    var filteredRows = instanceData.Select("ID = '" + row[item.ColumnName] + "'");
                    if (filteredRows.Any())
                        row[item.ColumnName] = filteredRows[0][1];
                }
            }
        }

        return transformedDataTable;
    }
```

But, this method iterating all the datatables, and being very slow, when relationshipdata having more entities to transform. So, How can i optimize this code, to work a large number of datatables with large number of rows.

**Edited** : In most conditions, These data are not stored in DB, These are in memory, and in memory the count for these datatables can be increased or decreased.

Thanks.

Comment: If it is stored in memory does it need to be DataTable? Wouldn't it be more effective to load it into some structures like dictionries?

If you are initially loading it from database you can use simple and fast data reader to populate dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to create a hash based collection (i.e. hashtables,dictionary,lookups in .NET)
with the ID column being the key and using that instead of the .Select(Id = x)

Code could look something like this.... Untested.

```
public static DataTable TramnsformRelationshipData(DataTable relationshipData, Dictionary<string, DataTable> mapping) 
    { 
        Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,DataRow>> newMappings = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,DataRow>>();
        foreach (var kvp in mapping)
        {
            newMappings.Add(kvp.Key,kvp.Value.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToDictionary(dr=>dr["ID"] as string));
        }

        DataTable transformedDataTable = null; 
        if (relationshipData == null || mapping == null ) 
           return null; 

        transformedDataTable = relationshipData.Copy(); 

        foreach (DataColumn item in relationshipData.Columns) 
        { 
            if (newMapping.ContainsKey(item.ColumnName)) 
            { 
                var instanceData = newMapping[item.ColumnName]; 
                if (instanceData == null) 
                    return null; 

                foreach (DataRow row in transformedDataTable.Rows) 
                { 
                //  var filteredRows = instanceData.Select("ID = '" + row[item.ColumnName] + "'"); 
                //  if (filteredRows.Any()) 
                    row[item.ColumnName] = instanceData[row[item.ColumnName]][1];                       
                } 
            } 
        } 

        return transformedDataTable; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered creating an SQL code (which will be much faster than using C# code) with `SELECT INTO` statement? I generally prefer to use SQL when I need to work with large amount of data.

Example taken from [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) page.

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, e.JobTitle, a.AddressLine1, a.City, sp.Name AS [State/Province], a.PostalCode
INTO dbo.EmployeeAddresses
FROM Person.Person AS c JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS e ON e.BusinessEntityID = c.BusinessEntityID
JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea ON e.BusinessEntityID = bea.BusinessEntityID
JOIN Person.Address AS a ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID
JOIN Person.StateProvince as sp ON sp.StateProvinceID = a.StateProvinceID;
```

First write a `SELECT` statement to get your data and then add the `INTO` statement.

Or you can user `INSERT` and `SELECT` where you can specify the list of columns to insert the data. Example taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) page.

```
INSERT INTO Production.ZeroInventory (DeletedProductID, RemovedOnDate)
SELECT ProductID, GETDATE() FROM ...
```

Comment: But, In most conditions, These data are not stored in DB, These are in memory, and in memory the count for these datatables can be increased or decreased.

Comment: You forgot to mention this in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like the problem itself is really simple, 3 joins could fix it if you were using sql.
I'm guessing the source isn't located in sql(if it is i would recomend creating a view there for maximum performance).
If you have to use datasets you can use linq to mimic a join.
Check this [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/01/26/querying-datasets-introduction-to-linq-to-dataset.aspx) on how to use linq with datasets.
You can find out how to do a join [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9#crossjoin)

 The end result would look something like this :

```
var q = from r in relations.AsEnumerable()
        join c in countries.AsEnumerable() on r.Country equals c.Id
        join con in continents.AsEnumerable() on r.Continent equals con.Id
        select new { someval = r.someValue1, 
                     someval2 = r.someValue2, 
                     countryname = c.Name 
                     continent = con.Name};
```

Comment: I am aware, how to use linq with dataset. but the datatables are in any number and a datatable can have any number of rows and columns, and in question, I have mentioned there are N datatables.

Comment: I'm sorry, i missed that part. Have you tried adding the joins in a foreach using this syntax : var joined = q.Join(countries.AsEnumerable(), a => a.Country, b => b.Id, (a, b) => new {b.Somevalue ,a.CC1})